# c++ mfc project upgrade from vs2015 to vs2019 breaks application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdk, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I decided to migrate to visual studio 2019 for my mfc c++ application from visual studio 2015.
I have installed all the required SDKs and chose target platform Windows 10, version 10.0.18362.0 and toolset visual studio 2019 (v142). Previously in visual studio 2015 I had Windows 8.1 and v140.

Everything compiles and I can debug the application, however I get strange behaviour for CSingleLock and CCriticalSection where static CCriticalSection objects are null or invalid causing null reference crashes. Static variables seem to have a mind of their own having random values in child frames. The application will open one child frame, but I cannot open multiple child frames simultaneously as the treecontrol in the main frame is misbehaving and will not change on click, the clicks are registered but the treecontrol is unable to get a handle to the ParentFrame (GetParentFrame) to open a new frame. Nothing untoward shows up in the output windows.

In visual studio 2019 I then changed toolset to v140 (Visual studio 2015) and all works as expected.

Has anyone got anything similar happen to them, is there anything I need to do different in code between the two toolsets or does anyone have any suggestions ?

I realise this post does not have much details as I am just fielding atm, if anyone needs more infro please let me know.

Comment: Without code, it's impossible to say anything.

Comment: How to create a [mcve] has instructions on how to isolate the issue.